# Filter unique data from text file based on specific columns without sorting

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have various text files with between 10-100k lines following the format below.

```
"2018-12-07 23:21:32",XX,99,ZZZ,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:25:17",XX,99,ZZZ,250,AVAILBLE
"2018-12-07 23:29:05",DD,11,AAA,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:30:00",CH,00,UUU,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:31:45",MM,33,OOO,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:46:41",XX,99,ZZZ,250,REMOVED
```

In the above example you can see that there are 3 records where columns 2, 3 and 4 are the same (XX,99,ZZZ - lines 1/2/6). I need to remove the first two lines so only the last remains.

The desired output would be as below.

```
"2018-12-07 23:29:05",DD,11,AAA,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:30:00",CH,00,UUU,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:31:45",MM,33,OOO,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:46:41",XX,99,ZZZ,250,REMOVED
```

I have a script working in PHP but for the files with 100k~ lines it's extremely slow and I am getting memory errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to remove all but the first of a sequence of duplicates than all but the last - you could try something like

```
$ tac file | awk -F, '!seen[$2 FS $3 FS $4]++' | tac
"2018-12-07 23:29:05",DD,11,AAA,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:30:00",CH,00,UUU,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:31:45",MM,33,OOO,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:46:41",XX,99,ZZZ,250,REMOVED
```

Comment: Awesome - I managed to put this together `awk -F, '!seen[$2$3$4]++' test > file2.csv` but wasn't sure about the sequence as you mentioned. The line you've put is working great and very fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN { FS = "," }

FNR == NR {
    if (seen[$2,$3,$4])
        delete lines[seen[$2,$3,$4]]

    lines[FNR]
    seen[$2,$3,$4] = FNR

    next
}

FNR in lines
```

This `awk` program expects to read the same file twice.  The first time it reads the file, only the `FNR == NR` block executes. This remembers, as keys in the `lines` array, what line numbers to output.  If a line with a particular combination of the 2nd, 3rd and 4th column has already been seen, the most recently line number is inserted as a key, and the previous is removed (the `delete` statement.

During the second parsing of the file, all that happens is that the current line number is looked up in the `lines` array.  If it's found, the line is printed.

Example run with a "one-liner" version of the same code:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR { if(s[$2,$3,$4]) delete l[s[$2,$3,$4]]; l[FNR]; s[$2,$3,$4]=FNR; next}; FNR in l' file file
"2018-12-07 23:29:05",DD,11,AAA,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:30:00",CH,00,UUU,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:31:45",MM,33,OOO,250,REMOVED
"2018-12-07 23:46:41",XX,99,ZZZ,250,REMOVED
```